# Finding common super classes in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

We need a SPARQL query to find the common superclasses for two Wikidata entities. I tried it like this:

```
select ?commonBase #?commonBaseLabel
where {
  wd:Q39798 wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?commonBase.
  wd:Q26868 wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?commonBase.
  #SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Here's](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3FcommonBase%20%23%3FcommonBaseLabel%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ39798%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20%3FcommonBase.%0A%20%20wd%3AQ26868%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20%3FcommonBase.%0A%20%20%23SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) a direct link to the query.

This always times out, even with the `SERVICE` line commented out.

However, when I run the same query with just one of the WHERE clauses, it runs very fast, yielding either 130 or 12 results.

Why is it so much slower with both WHERE clauses? In theory, the database could just perform both WHERE clauses separately and then do an INTERSECT, i.e. deliver those results that have occurred in both queries.

If this is a flaw in the design of the SPARQL engine, then how can I adapt the query to make it run faster?

Comment: https://w.wiki/BfY

Comment: As @StanislavKralin has shown sometimes the query optimizer doesn't find the best plan. Indeed, for users it's pretty hard to play around with the query hints, but at least disabling the query optimizer can be a fast check - if you're aware of those hints which aren't standard SPARQL. For your interest, adding `&explain` to the query URL returns the query execution plan

Comment: "adding &explain to the query URL returns the query execution plan" *when querying Wikidata and other Blazegraph-based services.* (`&explain` is not standard SPARQL.)